# create a Gaussian distribution with a customize covariance in Matlab

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, matlab

the Matlab function 'randn' randomize a Gaussian distribution with $\mu= \begin {pmatrix} 0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $cov= \begin {pmatrix} 1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$
Ineed to randomize a Gaussian distribution vector with $cov= \begin {pmatrix} 3&1\\1&3\end{pmatrix}$. how can I change the covariance matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Statistics Toolbox** has a function `mvnrnd`(see its [documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvnrnd.html)) to generate jointly Gaussian random variables with specified means and covariance matrix:

```
N = 10; % desired number of samples of each variable
mu = [10; 10]; % vector of means
cov = [3 1; 1 3]; % covariance matrix
samples = mvnrnd(mu, cov, N);
```

---

If you want to do it **manually**, you can generate independent standard Gaussian RV's (with `randn`) and apply an affine transformation that will give the desired mean vector and covariance matrix. For that you need to compute the Cholesy decomposition of the latter. See details for example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Drawing_values_from_the_distribution). Note that the output of Matlab's `chol` function (see its [documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/chol.html)) needs to be (conjugate-)transposed to conform to the procedure described in the link.

The code would be:

```
N = 10; % desired number of samples of each variable
mu = [10; 10]; % vector of means
cov = [3 1; 1 3]; % covariance matrix
independent_samples = randn(N, size(cov,1));
A = chol(cov)';
samples = bsxfun(@plus, mu, A*independent_samples.').';
```

Example realization with your inputs and `N=1e5` samples, plotted with

```
plot(samples(:,1), samples(:,2), '.', 'markersize', .1)
axis square
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to do so without the toolbox? (not with the same code obviously...)

Comment: Sure. See edited answer